# Is it possible to hide the "Listening..." popup that appears after "OK Google"?

Tags: voice-recognition, voice-command

It would be extremely helpful if I could say "OK Google" and issue voice commands without my screen being almost entirely covered by the white "Listening..." pop up.

Answer (score 1):

There are ways to achieve that:

1. **Using Google search widget**

   - If you have a Google widget, simply tap the mic and say "Okay Google, the window that appears is not covering whole scren but its almost half:

[image]

2. **Customising window with third-party tool (XHalo floating module)**

   - Good news is if you have root (and additionally Xposed framework), you can install the [XHaloFloatingWindow](http://repo.xposed.info/module/com.zst.xposed.halo.floatingwindow), pin the Google to Status bar and launch it fron there with a small sized window as shown:

[image]